# Is there a way to get the number of comments for each user and update it in the number_of_comments column automatically?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL like this

```
Users -> user_id , user_name , number_of_comments
Comments -> comment_id , comment , user_id
```

Is there a way to get the number of comments for each user and update it in the number_of_comments column automatically?

Comment: Do you need to achieve this goal in only one sql command?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: @derpirscher I mean without counting the comments by myself using PHP code

Comment: @LizhiLiu I'm not professional in MySQL but I'm trying to do that using restrict, cascade, set null, or, no action. I still search for a good way.

Comment: You can add a trigger on the comments table

Comment: *Is there a way to get the number of comments for each user* Easily. JOIN + GROUP BY + COUNT().  *and update it in the number_of_comments column automatically?* Not recommended. Query actual value when you need in it really.

Comment: @SC291 If a new comment record is inserted into `Comments` table, then increase `number_of_comments` field in the table `Users` of the corresponding `user_id`?

Comment: @derpirscher What about using restrict, cascade, set null, or, no action, something like this. Is the trigger the only way?

Comment: Create a view, will always be up-to-date.

Comment: @SC291 You want to implement it on mysql level rather than java (or php, c#, or any other development language)?

Comment: Any particular reason why need to update the table with number of comments?

Comment: @Akina But what if there were 1 million comments in the table that will take a long time to count them

Comment: No, you can't update a count with foreign key constraints

Comment: @jarlh Could you leave a more clear comment, Please

Comment: *But what if there were 1 million comments* Proper indexing will improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recommended, but solves nevertheless. For learning purposes only.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_update_n_of_comments
AFTER INSERT ON comments
FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE users
SET number_of_comments = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                           FROM comments
                           WHERE comments.user_id = NEW.user_id )
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
```

If the rows in `comments` may be updated (with `user_id` value changing) and/or deleted then create similar AFTER DELETE and AFTER UPDATE triggers.

PS. I strongly recommend you to remove `users.number_of_comments` column at all and calculate actual comments amount value by according query when needed.

---

If you agree that the value may be approximate (slightly different from the exact one), then you can use an incremental trigger.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_update_n_of_comments
AFTER INSERT ON comments
FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE users
SET number_of_comments = number_of_comments + 1
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
```

But just in case, provide for the creation of a service stored procedure (or event) that will periodically recalculate the accumulated value.

Comment: Facebook for example it is illogical to count comments for each user because I think it will take a long time if there was 1 million comments in the comments table.

Comment: I'll try to add 5 million comments in the table and back to you later to tell you what happened maybe 1 hour or less

Comment: @SC291 If you agree that the value may be approximate (slightly different from the exact one), then you can use an incremental trigger. But just in case, provide for the creation of a service stored procedure (or event) that will periodically recalculate the accumulated value.

Comment: I don't want to use triggers because I am afraid sometimes not works

Comment: @SC291 There is only one situation when the trigger not fires - cascade operations. Except some general failure, of course.

Comment: On Facebook there are billions of comments in the table I think, Do you think Facebook will create a loop for billions of comments to count comments of a specific post?

Comment: They probably don't have all their comments stored in a single MySQL table ...

Comment: @derpirscher No, but I have a comments system in my project, And we know is the data will increase day by day in the database. So I want to know if there were 50 million comments in the comments table for thousands of users is it will take a long time to get the number of comments for a specific user?

Comment: Yes, it probably will if you do it wrong. But tbh, the skills to build and manage such a system cannot be learned from a single stack overflow question ...